# Google drive only backup new photos

Tags: backup, photos, google

How can I only backup photo's I make after I turned on automatic backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all your existing photos into a different directory anywhere else. Then just be sure to not allow Google Photos to backup folders. It will by default grab just the DCIM/Camera folder.

Gallery/other file managers will still have full accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
Press the menu button

Settings>Automatic Backups

Backup all photos now

Comment: This is going to back up everything which the OP does not want.